# Как реализовать этот фрагмент кода для Mono for Android?

Tags: c#, java, android, monodroid

Как реализовать этот фрагмент кода для Mono for Android?

```
EditText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER){
                todoItems.add(0, myEditText.getText().toString());
                aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
                myEditText.setText("");
                return true;
            }       
            return false;
        }       
    });
```

Comment: отличный вопрос :)

Answer (score 1):

Примерно так:

```
EditText text = FindViewById<EditText> (Resource.Id.editText1);

if ( text != null )
{
    text.KeyPress += (sender, e) => {
        if ( e.KeyCode == Keycode.DpadCenter )
        {
                String s = text.Text;
                // Self staff.
                text.Text = "";
        }
    }
}
```